# Click function is running many times

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I have three audio link in href on a page as below-

```
<a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tuneables/Guided+Activities+Sounds/Do+bell.mp3" class="sound" title="D above middle C" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(5, 134, 209);">Do</a>

<a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tuneables/Guided+Activities+Sounds/Mi+bell.mp3" class="sound" title="F# above middle C" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(5, 134, 209);">Mi</a>

<a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tuneables/Guided+Activities+Sounds/So+bell.mp3" class="sound" title="A above middle C" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(5, 134, 209);">Sol</a>
```

Now I want to play all these three audio in Html5 audio on same page  without redirecting to href link on their click. So I wrote this Jquery code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $j(document).ready(function() {   
            $j('.sound').click(function(event) {

                        var str =this.href;
                        var sound='<audio class="audio" controls><source src="'+str+'" type="audio/ogg"><source src="'+str+'" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>'; 
                        $j(sound).trigger('play');
                        return false;
          });
       });  
</script>
```

but this code executes three times on click on any audio link and then play that audio three times simultaneously. I want to play audio only one time.

I hope somebody will understand my problem and help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your code is good! is the mp3 files that sounds 3 times, not the event

Comment: doesn't look like it to me:  http://jsfiddle.net/c8tuqqcb/

Comment: Hello@swatkins..this fiddle shows exactly what I need. but in chrome browser audio is triggered three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (add event.stopImmediatePropagation() there)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $j(document).ready(function() {   
            $j('.sound').click(function(event) {

                        var str =this.href;
                        var sound='<audio class="audio" controls><source src="'+str+'" type="audio/ogg"><source src="'+str+'" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>'; 
                        $j(sound).trigger('play');
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation()
                        return false;
          });
       });  
</script>
```